# How to change a string to Uri

Tags: android, uri

I am getting (what I believe) is a string from my hashmap and need to return this from my method as a Uri in order to use it in a VideoView.  Here is my method that gets the string from my hashmap:

```
public static Uri getVideoPath(String cond){
        Log.d(DEB_TAG, "*********Inside of getVideoPath");

        HashMap hm = createHashmap();

        Log.d(DEB_TAG, "********Value of hm is " + hm.get(cond));
        Uri tempPath = (Uri) hm.get(cond);

        return tempPath;
    }
```

I get a value for my "hm.get(cond)"  of this "http://www.personal.psu.edu/tmv105/video/sunny/sunny.mp4"  I get no value for "tempPath" which is the value that I am passing over to the call of this method like this: (mVid is my VideoView)

```
mPath = LayoutConditions.getVideoPath(wd.getCurrentIconCode());
mVid.setVideoURI(mPath);
mVid.requestFocus();
mVid.start();
```

Any ideas how I might handle this?  Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri tempPath = Uri.parse((String)hm.get(cond));
```

Comment: Works fabulously!  Thanks! :)